# Colspan and table-layout:fixed break my table style

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table where I need the rows to have specific widths. But colspan and table-layout:fixed break the style I want. 
Note that I can **NOT** change anything in the html code, I also **can't remove the table-layout:fixed.** Is what I want possible to do with only css? Or is it something that can't be done unless the html is changed?

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

td:nth-child(2),
tr:last-child th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

td:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

td:nth-child(4),
th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

td:last-child,
th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th colspan="4">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here is the visual of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2qFP.png)

[Here is the visual of what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq7WG.png)

Comment: use colspan in td you will get exact solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table layout fixed means that the table will use the first row to define it styles - as you have a colspan of 4 in your first row, it will not know what widths to give to the columns in the second row and therefore splits them equally.

[From MDN about table layout fixed:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

In order to get around this, you can define a [`colgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup) and then give your widths to those columns and they will be applied to the rest of the table:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

col:first-child {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

col:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

col:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

col:nth-child(5) {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
    </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1">1</th>
      <th colspan="4">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="col1">a</th>
      <th class="col2">b</th>
      <th class="col3">c</th>
      <th class="col4">d</th>
      <th class="col5">e</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you cannot change the html, and you have to have layout fixed, then you cannot do anything about the widths of the second row.

The best you can do with purely css is to remove the layout fixed (you didn't explain why this is needed) and just style the tds:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th colspan="4">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The table I'm working on uses a framework which already has a style. Since I'm pretty much overriding it, there are some parts that wont work the way they should unless I find the code which overrides it. The reason why I wanted to keep the layout fixed is because it made everything work, except for the widths. However I can see that achieving what I want is not possible, not with the way the code is written. I will have to find a different solution. I appreciate all the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
table-layout:fixed
```

apply when the table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in other rows do not affect column widths - [table-layout property understanding](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp), so you need to give
table {
table-layout: auto!important;
}

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

td:nth-child(2),
tr:last-child th:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

td:nth-child(3),
th:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

td:nth-child(4),
th:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

td:last-child,
th:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th colspan="6">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th colspan="3">b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td colspan="3">b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td colspan="3">b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td colspan="3">b</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can not change anything in the html. I can only work with the css code.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/razibmahmud50/3dt0osjL/6/)

```css
/*I think this is the minimal way**/
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th >1</th>
      <th colspan="19">2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td>a</td>
      <td colspan="14">b</td>
      <td colspan="2">c</td>
      <td colspan="2">d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td colspan="14">b</td>
      <td colspan="2">c</td>
      <td colspan="2">d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td colspan="14">b</td>
      <td colspan="2">c</td>
      <td colspan="2">d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```